# Saving ArcGIS Pro symbology to PostGIS DB for each layer

Tags: postgis, arcgis-pro, symbology

I want to have a default style/symbology assigned to each layer in a PostGIS database so that whenever it is loaded in ArcGIS Pro, it will come up with the default style.

There is a way in QGIS to save styles to PostGIS DB so that whenever the layer is dropped to the canvas it will come with the default style, but the style saved in DB will be a qml file and hence will not work with ArcGIS Pro.

I am looking for a way to add style to DB such that they load in ArcGIS Pro as most of the users for the tool I am developing will be using ArcGIS Pro to connect to the DB.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000012539, check if this helps

Comment: How about converting symbology to representation?

Comment: @YogeshChavan can representations be stored inside PostGIS DB and will the symbology load by itself if there is representation attached with a layer in DB. Sorry I have never worked with representations before.

Comment: i attempted to write a few answers, but hit quite a few snags. technically this methodology of retrieving style settings from a database is implemented in other systems (other than QGIS) but I think one of the stumbling blocks in ArcMap will be lyr file, its very closed off. For ArcPro, have a look here https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/symbol-class.htm

Comment: @nr_aus How can the methodology listed in the link for ArcPro work with a PostgreSQL database? I don't see that anywhere in the link. It talks about python scripts to apply symbology.

Comment: That link shows how symbology is retrieved using arcpy. 'applySymbolFromGallery' is the method. Modification/sub-class of this method to retrieve the style settings from a pg db is probably where I would apply a solution.

Comment: If your users will be using ArcGIS Pro, you should just [create layer files](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/save-to-layer-file.htm) and include them in an [ArcGIS Pro package](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/package-project.htm).  The layer files will use your database connection, but also apply the desired symbology for all users that extract the ArcGIS Pro package.